# How to get the Woocoomerce subtotal value without tax in the hardcode?

Tags: php, code

I'm trying to find the subtotal value without tax in the hard-code. I want to use the value after people have completed an order and run some code there.

I thought it was `$order->get_line_subtotal();` but that gave 0 as value when I used it in the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$order->get_subtotal()` should get you totals before taxes, coupons and shipping. It's a method of `WC_Abstract_Order` which is extended by the actual `WC_Order` class.

Comment: Btw cleverguy, Is it that easy to get coupons too? $order->get_coupons() to get couponnames? :-)

Comment: @MadsSpjøtvoldBerland Looks like `$order->get_used_coupons()` should do get you just that. Cheers!

Comment: Yes nice, thx! But that gives an array. Thought echo $($order->get_used_coupons())[0]; would output the first coupon name, but didnt work, this is php, not perl! :P